# Regex Pattern Matching until the first whitespace before the first series of characters containing a specific character

Tags: regex

Consider the following string:

```
ab cd ef gh/
```

How would I extract `ab cd ef`?
I would like to be able to match until the first whitespace before the first series containing a specific character, which in the case above is `/`.

EDIT: I'm trying to set a config file to parse some logs into Logstash, so I was wondering whether it was possible to do this just with regex rules.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: In case of no `/` (if that is possible) what is your expected result? And for the case of no whitespace before the `/`? Are there other edge cases that should be considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([^\/]+)\s+[^\/]*\/
```

Explanation:

```
(      start of Subpattern
[^\/]+ match one or more Elements that are no /.
       ^ is the Negation-Operator
       / needs to be escaped.
       + stands for one or more
)      end of Subpattern
\s+    match one or more Whitespaces
[^\/]* match no or any amount of Characters that are not a /
       * stands for Zero or any Amount 
\/     match /
```

The content of the Subpattern returns the Match.

Example:

```
preg_match('/([^\/]+)\s+[^\/]*\//', $input, $result);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason, none of the answers seem to work for me - however, yours was definitely the most helpful. Thanks for taking the time to explain each portion of your rule - it's my first time handling regex rules today and your answer has helped immensely.

Comment: You are welcome! I edited my posting as I forgot to change a + to * in my Regex. You can check how it works here: https://regex101.com/r/135xJO/1

Comment: @River you should have mentioned the language you are using... Flavors implementations may differ each other

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```js
function matchInString(str) {
  regex = /(.*) \w*\/\w*/
  m = str.match(regex)
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1])
  }
}

matchInString("ab cd ef gh/")
matchInString("ab cd ef gh/asdfasdf")
matchInString("ab cd ef gh/asdfasdf a/")
matchInString("ab cd ef gh/asdfasdf a/b")
matchInString("ab cd ef 12341234 /")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should suit for your specific case, assume it as a starting point:

```js
console.log(
  'ab cd ef gh/'.match(/(.*?)\s*(?:\w+\/)/).pop()
)
```